# shriek-star base change for cohomology of quasi-coherent sheaves on schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

Suppose we have a cartesian diagram of schemes as follows

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
V @>{j}>> Y\\
@V\pi VV @VV pV\\
U @>{i}>> X
\end{CD}

Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf on $Y$.

My question is: under which conditions there is a natural isomorphism as follows

$$ i^!p_*\mathcal{F} \to \pi_*j^!\mathcal{F}$$

here all the functors $i^!,p_*,\pi_*,j^!$ are the derived one.

Thank you!